# wp-admin redirects to standard wordpress page

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, template-redirect

I installed a Wordpress theme (NRGhost). It installs a plugin to use shortcodes (NRGhost Plugins) and other features. 
The plugin creates a custom redirect on wp-admin and redirects it to a custom page, which I don't need.  
Disabling the plugin stops the redirect. How do I change this redirect? Is there any way I can stop this redirect without disabling this plugin? Or may be a create custom hard redirect of some sort to make the wp-admin work as it was working before?

The website URL, in question, is http://www.juicescale.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem was, but updating Wordpress core and plugins fixed the issue. The webiste redirects to wp-admin as it should.